# ¿Cómo capturo el evento de una opción seleccionada de una datalist con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Cómo obtengo el valor seleccionado de una `datalist` con `jquery` y poder obtener los data atributos del seleccionado?

Por ejemplo:

```html
<form>
    <input list="foros" />
    <datalist id="foros">
        <option value="HTML" data-ejemplo='Editor' data-ejemplo2='sistemaoperativo'>
        <option value="CSS">
        <option value="Javascript">
        <option value="PHP">
    </datalist>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#foro").on('input', function () {
   var val=$('#foro').val();
   var ejemplo = $('#foros').find('option[value="'+val+'"]').data('ejemplo');
   alert(ejemplo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input id="foro" list="foros" />
    <datalist id="foros">
        <option data-ejemplo="Editor" value="HTML">
        <option data-ejemplo="Estilo" value="CSS">
        <option data-ejemplo="Cliente" value="Javascript">
        <option data-ejemplo="Programacion" value="PHP">
    </datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: Maravillosa solución que ni en el SO en inglés encontré. Muchas gracias! Por cierto, en lugar de usar el ....on('input'... utilicé ....on('change'... ya que lo estoy usando para enviar datos al servidor y no quiero que la función ocurra cada vez que tipeo.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $(document).ready(function()
         {
         $("input[name=eleccion]").change(function() {
          var value=$("input[name=eleccion]").val();
                var data=$('#foros [value="' + value + '"]').data('ejemplo');
              alert(value+" "+ data);
          });
         });
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <form name="formulario" id="formulario" action="/demos/2013/05-html-form-datalist.php" method="POST">
            
          Escribe  (html, css, javascript, php): 
            <datalist id="foros">
                <option value="HTML" data-ejemplo='Editor' data-ejemplo2='sistemaoperativo'>
                <option value="CSS">
                <option value="Javascript">
                <option value="PHP">
            </datalist>
         
            <input name="eleccion" list="foros">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
```

aca dejo un screenshot que demuestra la funcionalidad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: un +1 por el tiempo dedicado a responder es muy interesante las dos respuestas muy buenas sobré todo porque son distintas.